# Trying To Create Loop With Insert Statement

Tags: sql-server, loops

We have a table that stores security values for:

- a specific user `group` (could be up to 65 different user groups)
- security `filter` (there are 13 different security filters)
- `field`s (could be up to 35,000)
- `security type` (2 options.. read only, unavailable)

Today, this table only holds data where security is applied to said `Group`, `Filter` and `Field` and the assumption is that is there is not a row for that specific `field` and `filter` for a `group`, then they have access to the `field`.

I need to create a copy of the table and run a script that will cycle between all `field ID`'s. And say for Group 1 it will then cycle through all security `filters` and then security `type` and if there is not a row, then it will insert a row with values associated with the cycled logic (`field`, `group`, `filter` and `security type`).

**Table setup**

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbmSecFieldGroup](
    [groupID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [fldID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SecID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [typeID] [smallint] NOT NULL`
```

**Table data**

[image]

After reviewing the table data, you can see that there is only 1 security group visible in the window and that there are multiple `field ID`s (3256, 3257, 3258, 3259) and multiple security filters (7, 32, 36, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...). Looking at `field` `3257`, the expected result I am trying to get is that 8 rows would be inserted for security filter of `1,2,3,4,5,8,9` (ignore the number format is off, so there is a large gap from 11 to 32) with the same `Group ID` and same `field ID`, `#3257`.

I hope that I explained the problem I am having accurately, I know this needs to be some kind of loop, but this is over my head on what I have been able to self-teach so far so I don't know if this is possible or not.

Comment: Your question is unclear and too broad, but it doesn't sound like anything that would require loops, a merge combined with a single select statement should do the job. I'd start with editing your question and add **as text** sample data and expected output (in table form!), and at least an attempt of doing it yourself.

Comment: You might want to investigate a `cross join` which generates every possible combination - it sounds like this is what you're after